# Accessing var from another class or scene in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a game in `SpriteKit` that includes a player to select a character out of 7 options. Scene 1 will include 7 images. Each image will represent one character. The player will select the character by pressing on the image selected and new scene 2 will be presented. I want the selected character image to appear on scene 2. I saved data of selected character in scene 1, but when scene 2 is presented, it always shows character 1 and not another. Please advise what is the correct line of code to access var from scene 1 and bring it over to scene 2.

```
import SpriteKit

class Scene1: SKScene {

var Player1 = SKSpriteNode()
var Player2 = SKSpriteNode()
var Player3 = SKSpriteNode()
var Player4 = SKSpriteNode()
var Player5 = SKSpriteNode()
var Player6 = SKSpriteNode()
var Player7 = SKSpriteNode()

var playerSelect1 = false
var playerSelect2 = false
var playerSelect3 = false
var playerSelect4 = false
var playerSelect5 = false
var playerSelect6 = false
var playerSelect7 = false

// in touches began..
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.player1 {
        playerSelect1 = true
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"playerSelect1")

// then i present scene2

} else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.player2 {
        playerSelect2 = true
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"playerSelect2")

//then i present scene2

} else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.player3 {
        playerSelect3 = true
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"playerSelect3")

//then i present scene2

} else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.player4 {
        playerSelect4 = true
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"playerSelect4")

//then i present scene2
// i didn't list all 7 characters to make code shorter


class Scene2: SKScene {
var playerSelected: Scene1()

// did move to view
var character1 = SKSpriteNode()
var character2 = SKSpriteNode()
var character3 = SKSpriteNode()
var character4 = SKSpriteNode()

//grab the selection value
let playerSelect1 =          NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("playerSelect1")

let playerSelect2 =          NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("playerSelect2")

let playerSelect3 =          NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("playerSelect3")

let playerSelect4 =          NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("playerSelect4")

if playerSelect1 == true {
self.addChild(character1)
} else if playerSelect2 == true {
self.addChild(character2)
} else if playerSelect3 == true {
self.addChild(character3)
} else if playerSelect4 == true {
self.addChild(character4)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's consider the first time the user selects player 1. You store the selected player as a `Bool` in `NSUserDefaults`. This value will persist in local storage until you change it, *even after the app is closed*. So the next time the user selects player 2, you set the `Bool` for `playerSelect2`. The problem is, that in `Scene2` you start your `if` statement checking if `playerSelect1 == true`, which it is because you set it to `true` once and never changed it back. With your current method, you would have to set the desired `playerSelect` to `true`, but also reset all of the others to `false`. I would recommend changing your strategy to store a `String` corresponding to the selected player in `NSUserDefaults`. Something like this should get you started.

When you want to set the selected player:

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.player1 {
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("playerSelect1", forKey: "selectedPlayer")
else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.player2 {
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("playerSelect2", forKey: "selectedPlayer")
else if ...
```

When you want to determine which player was selected in `Scene2`:

```
//grab the value from local storage
let selectedPlayer = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("selectedPlayer") as! String

if selectedPlayer == "playerSelect1" {
        //handle player 1 case
}
else if selectedPlayer == "playerSelect2" {
        //handle player 2 case
}
```

Answer (score 1):

About your question there are many ways you can follow to achieve what you want. Now I personally only use `NSUserDefaults` when I need to communicate with for example to a today extension. You might also want to save your data files at a later time so  I thought to this:

```
class Settings: NSObject { // NSCoding in case you want to save your data
    var playerGender: [Bool]! = [Bool]()
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(playerGender, forKey: "playerGender")
    }
    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        playerGender = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("playerGender") as! [Bool]
    }
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.playerGender = Array(count:7, repeatedValue:false)
    }
}
class GameManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = GameManager()
    var settings : Settings! = Settings()
}
class Scene1: SKScene {
    let gameManager = GameManager.sharedInstance
    var player : [SKSpriteNode]?
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // in touches began..
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.player1 {
            gameManager.settings.playerGender[0] = true
        }
    }
}
class Scene2: SKScene {
    let gameManager = GameManager.sharedInstance
    var character : [SKSpriteNode]?
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //grab the selection value
        let playerSelect1 = gameManager.settings.playerGender[0] //it's true
    }
}
```

**Explaination**:
`Settings` is a class where you can write your game settings, and in future , you can also save the property values to a file.

`GameManager` is a shared instance, you can call it where do you want.